# Raspi: Using Python Script In A Python Script

Tags: python, import

On my Raspberry Pi I want to have 2 Python files:

- one contains my functions to drive a car: `functions.py`
- one contains the structure of the program: `drive.py`

How can I get access to `functions.py` when I write code in `drive.py`?
I tried with `import functions` and `import functions.py` in `drive.py`, but didn't work...

At this point it says:

> NameError: name "forwards" is not defined.

[drive.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oel6U.png)
[functions.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsoHO.png)

Both files are in the same directory...

Comment: Alway try to add some code to StackOverflow. Dont just add images of your code as it will help other to make edits to your code and get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to prefix the function name by the library name and it should work.

```py
import functions as F
...
...
#functions from other script:
F.forwards()
```